# Using variable spearation to solve a linear ODE of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I want to solve the ODE:

$$f'(x) + 2f(x) = 3$$

I want to use variable separation, so I get:

$$ f'(x) = 3 - 2f(x)$$

Now I want to divide by $3-2f(x)$ but I am unsure what I need to assume on $f$ in order to do that. That is, does that expression have to be non zero for all x, or only for a certain x? After that point I know what to do but I don't understand what I am supposed to do here.

thanks

Comment: If between for certain $x$ or all $x$, is your question, it should be for all x, that means $$f(x) \ne \frac 3 2$$ for any $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant function $f(x)=\frac32$ is one solution. All *other* solutions must satisfy $f(x) \neq \frac32$ for all $x$ since solution curves can't cross (by the uniqueness theorem), so they are given by $f'(x)/(3-2 f(x))=1$ and so on (the usual procedure).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor). That is, we wish to find a $g(x)$ so that 
$$
\begin{align}
(f(x)g(x))'
&=g(x)f'(x)+g'(x)f(x)\\
&=g(x)(f'(x)+2f(x))\\
&=3g(x)
\end{align}
$$
which happens when $g'(x)=2g(x)$. This can be solved with $g(x)=e^{2x}$. Then
$$
\left(e^{2x}f(x)\right)'=3e^{2x}
$$
which is much easier to solve.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to solve the ODE, you 've first to solve the homogenueos equation, i.e. $f'(x) + 2f(x) = 0$ and then fing the particular integral. You can easily rearrange the homogeneous equation as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=-2
\end{equation}
So that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{f}=-2 dx
\end{equation}
When integrating you get $f(x)=c e^{-2 x}$, where c is the integration constant. Your particular integral is a simple constant, since the right hand side of your differential equation is a constant. The solution is $f(x)=c e^{-2 x}+ 3/2$

Comment: Please read again the question. It was explicitly about a detail of the **separation of variables method**. In your answer, the equivalent question is why can you exclude division by zero when you divide by $f$.

Comment: Hi LutzL, thank you for your comment. When dividing by $3-2 f(x)$ clearly $f(x) \neq \frac{3}{2}$ however $3/2$ is the particurlar integral of the equation, so it is a solution. I just had a doubt that Eloo applied the separation of variable in the wrong way, i.e. to the full ODE and not to the homogeneous equation only. But strinctly speaking, when reading the question, you're right.

Comment: That was the point of doing that way, to avoid going over the homogeneous equation. More explicitly, a new dependent variable $g=3-2f$ is considered, then $g'=-2f'=-2g$ leading to $g=ce^{-2x}$ etc.

Comment: I understand your explanation. I just had a different reading.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the variable separation method, i think you need to solve the homogeneous equation the find a particular solution.

$$E: f'(x)+2f(x)=3 $$
Then, $$ E_h: f_h'(x)+2f_h(x)=0$$
for $f\neq 0$, we have,
 $$\frac{df_h}{f_h}=-2dx $$
by integration we have,
$$ \ln(|f_h(x)|)=-2x+C,\quad C\in \mathbb{R}$$
Which gives,$$ f_h(x)=Ke^{-2x},\quad K=e^C$$
know we can find a particular solution $f_p(x)$ using the variation of the constant method.
and finaly the general solution $f=f_h+f_p$

Comment: Please read again the question. It was explicitly about a detail of the **separation of variables method**. In your answer, the equivalent question is why can you exclude division by zero when you divide by $f_h$, what justifies the assumption $f_h\ne 0$.

Comment: The assumption i made is part of the process so i can divide by $f$ but the form of the solution that i get is what i need to be concerned about. Which means in the case of homogeneous solution $f_h(x)=Ke^{-2x}\neq 0\ \forall x$ so it is well defined as a solution. Also in the case of the general solution: $f=Ke^{-2x}+\frac{3}{2}\neq \frac{3}{2},\forall x$ so it is indeed a well defined solution of the given probelm.

Comment: The question was, why is that part of the process, what is the justification to proceed this way. The answer by Hans Lundmark gives the reason for that in a short and direct argument.